# I need automatically updated column which can get information from other tables and give me the updated information

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm developing an automation for my warehouse so I created `warehouse` which contains general information:

```
| warehouse | CREATE TABLE `warehouse` (
  `gn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gid` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gn`,`gid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `gid` (`gid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

because I have lots of goods .
In my warehouse the goods will be sold and definitely it'll be fulfilled by other resources so I need to have two other tables to record my in and out of my warehouse like below:

```
| warehousein | CREATE TABLE `warehousein` (
  `gid` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ia` float NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `cn` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  KEY `gid` (`gid`),
  CONSTRAINT `warehousein_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`gid`) REFERENCES `warehouse` (`gid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

and

```
| warehouseout | CREATE TABLE `warehouseout` (
  `cstid` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gid` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oa` float NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  KEY `wgout` (`cstid`,`gid`),
  KEY `fk_wgido` (`gid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_wcstno` FOREIGN KEY (`cstid`) REFERENCES `customer` (`cstid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_wgido` FOREIGN KEY (`gid`) REFERENCES `warehouse` (`gid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

Now, in `Amount` column in `warehouse` I need to have updated `amount` which is sum of `ia` (In Amount) from `warehousein` and `oa` (Out Amount) from `warehouseout` constantly and automatically.

what is your suggestion?

Comment: *"I need to have updated amount which is sum of ia (In Amount) from warehousein and oa (Out Amount) from warehouseout constantly and automatically."* *"what is your suggestion?"* Storing totals in a table is actually against anny normalisation form rules..  But if you really want you to you will have to go triggers and write three for insert, update and delete to recalculate

Comment: You can calculate the total as needed.  If that is not sufficient for your purposes, then you will need triggers -- and be sure to consider `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s.

Comment: I think it's better to do this specific thing in my django backend program and update the `warehouse` table.

Comment: Does `warehouse` contain the current quantity of each item?  And `warehousein` is a record of _each_ addition to the warehouse?  Or do they have some other semantics?